# Use java resource bundles for i18n in React

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, formatjs

I'm migrating relatively large java application to React and need to implement internationalisation in React application. Sure, there are many libraries available for i18n in React, like FormaJS and i18next but I found most of them not answering to my requirements:

1. All the translation is already done in form of java resource bundles where key and messages look like:

   ```
   simpleKey = Hi!
   multiParamterKey = Dear {0}, I have {1} messages for you
   formattingKey = Ticket {0,number,#} has been closed 
   multiLineKey = Dear {0}, \n\
   \n\
   Have a nice day \n\
   otherKey = ...
   ```

   We don't need pluralisation but want to avoid replacing numeric parameters `{0}` with named parameters `{key1}`, if possible, as it could be tricky especially, where format involved (formattingKey). Also I have to use existing keys.
2. The library should support locale for fallback translation. I.e. if I have German locale set as fallback locale and translating key for English, all the missing keys in _en file/source should be translated using  _ge file/source
3. (Ideally) Library should allow changing fallback and current locale dynamically
4. (Ideally) Library should allow loading bundles using ajax

I decided against FormatJS mostly because of id does not support fallback locales. It has a concept of default translations which should be provided in the component when used.

I close to decide against i18next as 
 - React integration project seems not very popular 
 - Need to change messages to use named parameters

Can anyone recommend some other libraries?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: I ended up implementing translation myself, it actually was super easy. In a core it just a map and then replace placeholders with values using `strformat(message, ...parameters);`